# Why is my avatar from Stack Exchange no longer used on Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, gravatar, avatar

Since I created my account years ago I used my gravatar avatar on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange.
but since last month my Stack Overflow avatar changed to something that looks like an automatically generated avatar.
However my original avatar picture has not changed on my network profile on https://stackexchange.com/users/465418/jens-timmerman

Why did this change occur all of a sudden?
How do I change my avatar on Stack Overflow to be the same as the one on my network profile?

My avatar on Stack Exchange.com is still my gravatar: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bbdebf9137340dfb14f7482c14246844?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG

My avatar shown anywhere else on Stack Overflow or other Stack Exchange sites is 
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/355452612bf8ed80ee87ba7567387c49?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1

I do not know how this change came to be, and how I can get ownership of the second gravatar?

update:
I noticed I have an Identicon and a gravatar image I can select
[image]

It seems like my picture switched to the Identicon on all sites in the network except on Stack Exchange.
I can change it back manually one-by-one, is there an option to change change this back to the previous behaviour?

Comment: The avatar on Stack Exchange is unlinked from individual sites. You can have one avatar on SE.com, one on SO.com, one on GD.SE... You can have as many unique profile pics as there's sites in the network. You can manually change it back, but gravatars don't just disappear. Could be a mod cleared it (by accident?), or that the system just derped and for whatever reason removed it. The latter seems more likely though